# Mapping between hadoop-1.2.1 and hadoop-2.2.0?

Tags: hadoop

I am currently reading [Hadoop in Action](http://www.manning.com/lam/) .The book is very good, however it uses hadoop 1.2.1 to explain and showcase all the examples. But, I am using hadoop 2.2.0.

Does anybody know where I can find a full documentation about hadoop api changes ? and a simple mapping between 1.2.1 and 2.2.0 ?

For examples

```
DataJoinMapperBase, DataJoinReducerBase, and TaggedMapOutput
```

Does not present in 2.2.0 and I am looking for there counterparts in 2.2.0 :)

Thanks

Comment: Put the book back in the library, go to the right upper corner and click "Update all"... "Paper is only for the classics"

Comment: I've got the part about the book but not the other "right upper corner " :D

Answer (score 0):

> "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, Third Edition" by Tom White  [(Buy Here)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520)

supports hadoop v2.2.

The **source code** is give on github  https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book

as mentioned on github, the code of the book is tested with

```
This version of the code has been tested with:
 * Hadoop 1.2.1/0.22.0/0.23.x/2.2.0
 * Avro 1.5.4
 * Pig 0.9.1
 * Hive 0.8.0
 * HBase 0.90.4/0.94.15
 * ZooKeeper 3.4.2
 * Sqoop 1.4.0-incubating
 * MRUnit 0.8.0-incubating
```

**Regarding your question** 
Hadoop 2.2 use mapreduce api v2 while Hadoop 1.x use old mapreduce api. Check this book, it clearly explain the mapreduce code difference between 1.x and 2.2.

hope it helps..!!!